# Displaying AJAX data on success not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Upon success, my data isn't displaying, the JavaScript alert pop up is blank. I was wondering if you could help. This is within an MVC C# context where I run function GradeCalc with grade parameter.

```
$("#test").on("change", function () {
        var gradeval = $("#Grade").val();   
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '/Grade/GradeCalc/',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ grade: gradeval }),
                    dataType: 'JSON',   
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                     },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
                    },
                });
        });
```

The C# return code is:

```
public JsonResult GradeCalc(string grade)
{
    //calculations etc are performed here........then
    return Json(ViewBag.Grades, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show more of your C# code

Comment: So, what is actually sent and returned in the request? Check in your devtools' network tab.

Comment: []
No properties

Comment: Does it hit the `GradeCalc` method with the parameter passed? Did you try adding a debug point? And no need to pass data like this since you pass a single parameter. `data: JSON.stringify({ grade: gradeval })`. Just pass `data: {'grade': gradeval }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi sup you can try console.log(data); then you see in browser console that you should have used alert(data.data); or what ever your actuall data are wrapped around alert(data.wrapperclass)